# Full path name of bash? and base process of Linux?

Tags: bash, process, path, init

I recently had the following questions:

- What is the full path name of bash?
- What is the base process of Linux?

I couldn't answer these.

Answer (score 3):

The base process in linux is named `init` and has the `PID` 1 
If you are on Linux, you can install the command `pstree` to have a tree view of the process, or using the command `ps -eF`. See also [Wikipedia: init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)

`bash` is probably (depending on your distribution) in `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash`

To identify the path of a command an easy thing to use is the command:

```
type bash
#you can also usee (but not recommanded)
whereis bash
command -v bash
```

It will read your path (or try to guess) and gives you several path where you can find the file `bash`

Comment: Most probably **not** `/usr/bin/bash` but `/bin/bash`

Comment: Yes you're both right... End of the week tired.. coffee... really sorry.

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` is not that uncommon (Arch Linux for example), but yes, it depends on the distribution.

Comment: To find out the full path you can also run 'which bash'. That should show the path that will be executed when you run just 'bash'

Comment: We shouldn't be recommending the use of `which` or `whereis`. If you're using Bash it should be `type`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: @slm does the answer appears more precise ;-) (the wich wheris ... article is very long)

Comment: Yes thanks for the edit, I encourage you to read it. You can read it in multiple goes if only to help you when answer Q's here that deal w/ which. We get enough of them so it's good to link that Q&A to help educate others. I was a long time `which` user and it's hard to disassociate the name from my memory now.

Comment: Why are `which` and `whereis` bad? (doh - then I opened the link - ignore me)